# how to make Jq script on Pardot shorten and more efficient

Tags: jquery, performance, dropdown, coding-efficiency, pardot

I wrote this code to make a dropdown menu set a class value on selection in order to know what I selected to make it red when a selection is required.

The thing is that it is Pardot and I can't change the HTML.
this is what I have a (the class was set by me)

```
p.Environment select option
```

The class changes for each dropdown
The  value is a number set by Pardot

any chance I can make this code just one function to work for all 3 dropdown but recognizing the dropdown I click?

```
<script>
// ---------Environment Dropdown Error-----------
(function() {
var selectedOption = 'option815221';
var drop = '.Environment';
$(drop).addClass(selectedOption);
$(drop+' select').change(function(){
    $(drop).removeClass(selectedOption).addClass("option"+$(this).val());
    selectedOption = "option"+$(this).val();
});
})();
// ---------Country Dropdown Error-----------
(function() {
var selectedOption = 'option815237';
var drop = '.country';
$(drop).addClass(selectedOption);
$(drop+' select').change(function(){
    $(drop).removeClass(selectedOption).addClass("option"+$(this).val());
    selectedOption = "option"+$(this).val();
});
})();
// ---------State Dropdown Error-----------
(function() {
var selectedOption = 'option824913';
var drop = '.state';
$(drop).addClass(selectedOption);
$(drop+' select').change(function(){
    $(drop).removeClass(selectedOption).addClass("option"+$(this).val());
    selectedOption = "option"+$(this).val();
});
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this oughta do the trick.

```
var optionsAndDrops = [
  ["option815221", ".Environment"],
  ["option815237", ".country"],
  ["option824913", ".state"],
];
optionsAndDrops.forEach(([selectedOption, drop]) => {
  $(drop).addClass(selectedOption);
  $(drop + " select").change(function() {
    $(drop)
      .removeClass(selectedOption)
      .addClass("option" + $(this).val());
    selectedOption = "option" + $(this).val();
  });
});
```

EDIT: Or, more clearly perhaps, wrapping the logic in a real named function and just calling it thrice:

```
function setupDropdown(drop, selectedOption) {
  $(drop).addClass(selectedOption);
  $(drop + " select").change(function() {
    $(drop)
      .removeClass(selectedOption)
      .addClass("option" + $(this).val());
    selectedOption = "option" + $(this).val();
  });
}

setupDropdown(".Environment", "option815221");
setupDropdown(".country", "option815237");
setupDropdown(".state", "option824913");
```

Comment: Wow !!! that was fast and accurate, thank you very much,
would you be kind to explain in words the principle behind it so I could learn, or maybe share a link about this method - Thanks again

Comment: It's just shoving the two values that vary in the otherwise identical segments in an array, and iterating over them.

Comment: Ok but how does it know what dropdown I am editing and how it chooses the correct optionsAndDrops and not just changing all of the them?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, so if we call it 3 times how come it only happens once and to the specific dropdown I choose?

Comment: Because we pass in the specific dropdown and class as parameters.